# How to redirect and render page in the same function?

Tags: go, http

I am trying to authenticate a login and redirect to "/" after a successful login. The login function is condensed and normally the redirect is enclosed in a POST statement. In either case, the redirect returns the error "http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from main.handleLogin." Is it possible to render the page and redirect upon successful authentication?

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/join", handleJoin)
    http.HandleFunc("/login", handleLogin)
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleHome)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
func handleLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("login.html"))
    if err := t.Execute(w, nil); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
    return
}
```

Tried redirecting in Javascript with AJAX request, interfered with setting cookies

Comment: When you redirect, you should not send a body. If you send a body, you should not redirect. What exactly are you trying to do? The problem is because when you execute the template, it writes the body, and to write the body, it first writes the header. Once the header is written, you cannot change it. `Redirect` tries to write the header again, but it is already sent, hence the message.

Comment: You can redirect from the page itself using the JS api.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the body of the handler function based on the request method.

```golang
func handleLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case http.MethodGet:
        t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("login.html"))
        if err := t.Execute(w, nil); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }

    case http.MethodPost:
        // parse login input from request's body
        // check login input against data in db
        // on success redirect
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
    }
}
```